# SQL ORACLE ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I know what this error means but I do not understand why I am getting it. I think I did the question right. Please help. Question, ERD and code below. I am using Oracle SQL Developer. Thanks in advance!

> For each stock exchange, display the symbol of the stock with the highest total trade volume. 
>   Show the stock exchange name, stock symbol and total trade volume.  Sort the output by the name of the stock
>   exchange and the stock symbol.

```
SELECT 
  se.name,
  se.stock_ex_id,
  sl.stock_symbol,
  SUM(t.shares) AS total_trade_volume
FROM stock_exchange se
  JOIN trade t
    ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
  JOIN stock_listing sl
    ON sl.stock_id = t.stock_id
   AND sl.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
HAVING SUM(t.shares) IN (SELECT MAX(total_shares)
                         FROM (SELECT stock_ex_id,
                                      stock_id,
                                      SUM(shares)
                               FROM trade
                         WHERE stock_ex_id IS NOT NULL
                         GROUP BY stock_ex_id, stock_id)
                         GROUP BY se.stock_ex_id, se.name, sl.stock_symbol
                         ORDER BY se.name, sl.stock_symbol
```

ERD:

[image]

Comment: You are missing a comma before `SUM()`in the subquery.

Comment: I think you are missing a closing parenthesis "stock_id))" to close the subquery

Answer (score 2):

Several syntax errors, including:
HAVING clause before GROUP BY
missing alias of a column
I tried correcting these and others:

```
SELECT 
  se.name,
  se.stock_ex_id,
  sl.stock_symbol,
  SUM(t.shares) AS total_trade_volume
FROM stock_exchange se 
JOIN trade t ON se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
JOIN stock_listing sl ON sl.stock_id = t.stock_id AND sl.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
GROUP BY se.stock_ex_id, se.name, sl.stock_symbol
HAVING SUM(t.shares) IN (
  SELECT MAX(total_shares)
  FROM (
    SELECT stock_ex_id, stock_id, SUM(shares) AS total_shares
    FROM trade
    WHERE stock_ex_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY stock_ex_id, stock_id
  )
)
ORDER BY se.name, sl.stock_symbol
```

Also, although not syntactically wrong, the `IN` clause is useless and instead you can use `=`.